# HD Sata 3.0, how to recover data?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery

I have an old pc (it doesn't turn on anymore and I don't want to recover it) with some useful and other important data on the internal HD.

This is the guy: http://www.directron.com/6v080e0.html

I need to recover data from this so I'm asking you how to connect this old HD to my laptop? Is there something like an adapter or cable to connect it to my usb port? Does it require power to work (not like the 2.5 portable HD)?

Thanks for your kind answer.

Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are docking bays that can allow you to take the internal hard drive out of your old machine and plug it into the bay. The bay would then allow you to connect to your computer (typically through an USB interface). The hard drive would need external power (typically provided in these kind of kits). This would act similar to an external enclosure for your drive and would work for both desktops and laptops.

[image]

Just search NewEgg for *Hard Drive Docking* and many results will show you workable solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I heard about those docks and it's exactly what I'm looking for.